# Distinguishing between linear and non-linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a few problems from Dennis Zill's book on Differential equations and in te exercise below I am asked to say if the differential equation is linear or non-linear and its order:

[image: Exercises]

**My answers:**

1 - 2nd order, linear

2 - 3rd order, ?

3 - 4th order, linear

4 - 2nd order, non-linear

5 - 2nd order, non-linear

6 - 2nd order, non-linear

7 - 3rd order, linear

8 - 2nd order, ?

Can someone confirm that? I am really confused about a differential equation being linear or nonlinear.

Comment: $2.$ and $8.$ are nonlinear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An ordinary differential equation is linear if it can be written in the form
$$
L(y(x))=\left[A_n(x)\frac{d^n}{dx^n}+A_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}+ \cdots +A_1(x)\frac{d}{dx}+A_0(x)\right]y(x)=f(x)
$$

(this guarantees that if $h(x)$ and $k(x)$ are solutions , also $\alpha h(x)+\beta k(x)$ is a solution)
so, in your case , the equations 2,4,5,6,8 are not linear.

Comment: I am having a bit of confusion understanding your text. Is $$
\left[A_n(x)\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+A_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+ \cdots +A_1(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+A_0(x)\right]y=f(x)
$$ what you mean? Is there any restriction on the undifferentiated y term?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4527089/804033 this equation looks a bit different too, i am guessing it could be a formatting error?