# How to define linear and non-linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem understanding how to define a linear or non-linear Differential equation. These are my answers to the questions, however, my teacher's answers are not the same as mine.

Questions
[image: Questions]

His answers are

1.Linear

2.Non-Linear

3.Non-Linear

4.Linear

5.Non-Linear

6.Linear

Isn't the right-hand side of the equation has to be function of x or y alone? I extremely confused now, please help.

Comment: In order for you to use that heuristic, you had to move everything to one side first. The properties of the equations can't be dependent on which side of an equal side we decide to write them. It would still be the same (or equivalent, depending on how philosophical you want to get about it) equation no matter how the terms are distributed on either side of an equal sign.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720033/if-a-frac-dydx-by-c-has-constant-coeffcients-does-that-means-that-a/3720045#3720045

Answer (score 2):

In an ODE $F(x,y,y',y'',..)=0$, if $y, y', y'', ...$ occur linearly (power 1) it can be linear. For example $y'=x+y^2, y'=2x+e^y, y'=3x+\sin(y),...$ are not linear. $y'^2=x+y$ is not linear.

On the other hand
$a(x)y''+b(x)y'+c(x)y=0$ is linear. It being second order if $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$
are its solution then $y(x)=y_1(x)+y(x)$ will always be a solution.

Suppose $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are solutions of an ODE then if $y(x)=C_1 y_1+C_2 y_2$ is also a solution, the ODE is a linear ODE. This can serve as a general method to check if a given ODE is linear or not.

Check that, despite $y$ and $y'$ occuring linearly the ODE: $(x+y)dx+(y-x)dy=0$
or equivalenly $y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$ is not linear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

A linear differential equation has the form

$$
c_0(x)y + c_1(x)\frac{d{y}}{dx} + \cdots c_k(x) \frac{d^ky}{dx^k} + \alpha(x) = 0
$$

where the $c_i(x)$ and $\alpha(x)$ are differentiable.

Comment: a(x) is something like x^2,〖xe〗^x,  sin⁡(x) which only have one variable in this case x, right? Or can it be like ye^x,ysin(x),x^4 y^5 with more than one variables and treated y as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

A linear differential equation of order n is an equation that can be written in the form
$$P_0(x) \frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+P_1(x) \frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+P_2(x) \frac{d^{n-2}y}{dx^{n-2}}+\cdots+P_{n-1}(x) \frac{dy}{dx}+P_n(x) xy=Q(x).$$
Facts on linear differential equation:

1. Degree of DE is 1
2. Exponent of each differential quotient of DE is 1
3. Exponent of each dependent variable, $y$, of DE is 1
4. No term contains product of dependent variable, $y$, and its differential coefficient, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, that is, $y\frac{dy}{dx}$.

For further discussion, check it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Xub0zCmlXk

So,
#1 is linear since facts (1-4) satisfies.

#2 is nonlinear since degree of DE is 4, that is, $\frac{d^3u}{dx^3}^4$.

#3 is nonlinear since there exist an exponent of dependent variable $y$ that is not 1.

#4 is linear since facts (1-4) satisfies.

#5 is nonlinear since degree of DE is 2, that is, $(y'')^2$.

#6 is linear since facts (1-4) satisfies.